# Type interpretations of a buffer

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I have a generic type called `Type` which can be anything.

Is the following fine to do in terms of undefined behaviour?

Have this struct

```
struct alignas(alignof(Type)) TypeBuffer {
    char buffer[sizeof(Type)];
}
```

And then freely `reinterpret_cast` between `Type` and `TypeBuffer`? Or generally use `TypeBuffer` as `Type`? Of course when I cast from `TypeBuffer` to `Type` and use it, I assume that that part of the memory has been constructed with placement new or someway.

If it is undefined, what are the reasons and what are my alternatives to have a Type view of a buffer?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at Variant and see what's going on with that?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Why not use `std::aligned_storage`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The reason I made this question was to understand if any problems can occur from this implementation, if not what would be the allowed or disallowed use cases of such a type.